# Where can I save at school?

Tags: persona-3-fes

In *Persona 3 Portable* I can save in one of these 3 locations:

- By the Sign-in counter at the dorms.
- At my desk at school.
- By the clock in Tartarus.

as well as a couple of other places, which are only available during special events, such as the beach in Yakushima and the hotel in Kyoto.

Now I'm playing *Persona 3 FES: The Journey* and I noticed that I can't save at my desk. I've been running around school and even around town looking for a place to save, but to no avail.

Where exactly can I save during the day, before returning to the dorms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Persona 3 FES for PlayStation 2 the only save points regularly available are the ground floor of dorm and the lobby of the Tartarus.

There are additional save points during special events like the trip to Yakushima but they are not regularly available.